# Apex - Converting Map to a string for REST response?

Tags: apex

I need to return a map that for my REST service. How does one return a map into a string so it can be returned as JSON?

```
// Psuedocode
global with sharing class MyService {
    //Map locations = ...
    // Convert locations to a string?
    RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(locations);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(locations));
```

JSON can handle almost any data type, including maps that include serializable types. The exceptions to this rule are items that can't be serialized, like SavePoint, SObjectField and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and help. However, it still gives me an error,  "Illegal Assignment error from String to Blob". Do i still have to convert it to a different type first?

Comment: @chrisjlee You're right. I meant to include Blob.valueOf. Try the update.

Comment: Great thanks. That seemed to let me compile. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to convert a Map to String you can do it by using `String.valueOf()`

```
Map<String, Integer> mapVal = new Map<String, Integer> {'zero' => 0, 'one' => 1, 'two' => 2, 'three' => 3};
String mapString = String.valueOf(mapVal);
```

I suspect what you want to do is really convert to JSON, which in that case you would do `JSON.serialize` as `sfdcfox` suggested.